# Generating a random numpy ndarray of 0 and 1 with a specific range of 1 values

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, probability, programming

I want to generate a random numpy ndarray of 0 and 1. I want that the number of occurrences of 1 in every specific rowto range between 2 and 5.
I tried:`x = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(10, 10))`yet i cannot control the number of ones.
I tried the np. random.choice() but we only can control the probability of the number. for instance, 1 will be 0.2 of the array. Yet, I want this probability to vary and be in a specific range.
I also tried this code for every row in of my ndarray.
`one_count = np.random.randint(2, 5))`

`zero_count = colnumber - one_count`

`my_array = [0] * zero_count + [1] * one_count`

`np.random.shuffle(my_array)`

Can you please help me in finding a  better solution?

Answer (score 2):

It ultimately depends on the nature of the underlying data for your simulation to represent that. For instance, if you have some type of censored Poisson process what I will show won't make sense as is.

But, one way is to generate *all* possible permutations that meet your criteria (here there end up being 627 possible permutations that meet {10 choose 2} + {10 choose 3} ... + {10 choose 5}). And then you can sample at random from that greater choice set.

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)

# Lets create the whole sets of possible permutation lists
res = []
zr = np.zeros(10)
for i in range(2,6):
    for p in it.combinations(range(10),i):
        on = zr.copy()
        on[list(p)] = 1
        res.append(on.copy())

resnp = np.stack(res,axis=0)

# Now lets sample 1000 from this list
total_perms = resnp.shape[0]
samp = np.random.choice(total_perms,1000)
res_samp = resnp[samp]

# Check to make sure this is OK
np.unique(res_samp.sum(axis=1),return_counts=True)
```

If you had observed data, you could generate probabilities from that observed data and feed into the `p` probability argument for `np.random.choice`.

In this scenario, there are more permutations for the 10 choose 5 than there are for the 10 choose 2, if you want those types of scenarios to happen with equal probability, you would set the *sum* of the probabilities for the 10 choose 2 scenarios to be equal to that of the 10 choose 5.